# Access Violation and Out of system resources in Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, bde

I have an application in Delphi 5, legacy, that after some implementations, Access Violation and Out of system resources began to occur at different points and no obvious reason for the problem occurs.

This system has several cast, where the main class can become several classes.

Example:

```
(Teste as TCaixa).Element
```

What or how can I do to try to discover the source of the problem?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. You have to isolate the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In debugging the problem happens not only in production, because of this I am not able to isolate the problem to try to resolve the error.

Comment: I don't mean stepping through the code. I mean debugging in general. Use debugging tools to isolate the problem. madExcept would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

From your errors, if it happens in production but not in your dev environment, then it might mean that the errors only occur with prolonged use.

- Look for unfreed objects for the out of system resources errors
- Look for uninitialized objects for the access violation errors

Due to the possible size of the legacy source, I will recommend trying to get stack traces and debug output from the production environment to give you a general direction that you need to look at.

Comment: Any suggestions for component or something similar, to find the error more easily

Comment: @mtsys, see [Ultimate guide to Debug in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3994802/576719).